# Nhibernate woes. Calling lock to reattach object throws exception "No persister for: MovieProxy"

Tags: nhibernate

Below is the code. Ive simplified it down to nothing. Basically i open a session, load the movie, test that lock works, then evict the item, then try lock it again and it throws the exception. Has anyone seen this before. I would appreciate it if anyone can help. There are no custom interceptors or anything. Im using fluent nhibernate mappings and nhibernate 3.3.1.4000.

var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();

var m = session.Get(movie.Id);

session.Lock(m, LockMode.None);

session.Evict(m);

session.Lock(m, LockMode.None);

i have created a simple class mapping to narrow down the problem. The problem appears to be a bug in lazy loading tagged to properties. Locking works fine when the lazy loaded phone number is commented out however crashes when its included in the mapping.

```
        //DynamicUpdate();
        //LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name).Unique();
        Map(x => x.CleanName);
        Map(x => x.PhoneNumber).LazyLoad();
        HasMany(o => o.CountryList).Table("Country").Element("String").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().LazyLoad();
        //HasMany(x => x.AddressList).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Inverse().LazyLoad();
        Version(x => x.EditDate);
```

Comment: i can confirm this is a bug, best would be to file it https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH

Comment: Problem is that the Proxies generated for lazy properties do not implement INHibernateProxy and session.Lock does not recognize LazyPropertyProxies